# Python timeit not working?

Tags: python, profiling

Can somebody explain me why this is happening?

```
aatiis@aiur ~ $ time python /usr/lib64/python2.7/timeit.py -n 1 \
    -- 'x = 10**1000'
1 loops, best of 3: 0.954 usec per loop

real    0m0.055s
user    0m0.050s
sys     0m0.000s

aatiis@aiur ~ $ time python /usr/lib64/python2.7/timeit.py -n 1 \
    -- 'x = 10**100000'
1 loops, best of 3: 0.954 usec per loop

real    0m0.067s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.020s

aatiis@aiur ~ $ time python /usr/lib64/python2.7/timeit.py -n 1 \
    -- 'x = 10**10000000'
1 loops, best of 3: 0.954 usec per loop

real    0m20.802s
user    0m20.540s
sys     0m0.170s
```

I get the exact same result from `timeit`, but `time` tells me that evaluating `10**10000000` takes more than 20 seconds. The same happens if I call `timeit` from the interpreter:

```
>>> t = time.time()
>>> print timeit.timeit('x = 10**10000000;', number=1)
5.00679016113e-06
>>> print time.time() - t
20.6168580055
```

Why is my `timeit` not working, or what am I doing wrong?

Additional info:

```
>>> print sys.version
2.7.1+ (2.7:4f07cacb2c3b+, Mar 28 2011, 23:11:59)
[GCC 4.4.5]

>>> print sys.version_info
>>> sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=2, releaselevel='alpha', serial=0)
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's another very interesting observation:

```
>>> def run():
...     t = time.time()
...     x = 10**10000000
...     print time.time() - t
```

When I press enter after defining this function, it takes about half a minute till I get back to a prompt. And then:

```
>>> run()
2.14576721191e-06
```

Why is that happening? Is the function body being pre-compiled or optimized somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def run():
...     return 10**100
... 
>>> dis.dis(run)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (100000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000L)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

And

```
>>> def runvar():
...     x = 10
...     return x**100
... 
>>> dis.dis(runvar)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  4           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (100)
             12 BINARY_POWER        
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notice that `BINARY_POWER` is executed at runtime only in the second case. So `timeit` behaves as it should.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is the problem is in how you're stating the problem to `timeit`.  I think what's happening is that the expression is being evaluated once when the test expression is compiled and then just looked at (rather than re-evaluated) with each timeit loop.  So currently all you're measuring is the time it takes to do the assignment rather than the calculation.

You'll need to force the calculation to happen each time:

```
timeit.timeit('x = 10; y = 100; z = x ** y')
```

Edit: in answer to your later question the function body is being optimized.  The compiler sees `10*100000` and realises that it won't ever change so calculates it at compile time rather than run time.

Comment: You're right, forcing calculation to happen each time does make it take longer. I didn't know Python will pre-calculate expressions for me.

Comment: @Attila - neither did I until now.

Answer (score 0):

It results in errors, put any comments before `%%timeit`:

```
#Example.......
%%timeit
df['distance'] = haversine_looping(df)
```

Do this instead, start the block with `%%timeit`:

```
%%timeit
df['distance'] = haversine_looping(df)
```